# `set -e` and `grep` idiom for preventing premature exit from shell script when pattern not found

Tags: bash, grep, gnu, coreutils

Help required - in the context of shell scripting on a GNU/LINUX bash:

I always use `set -e`. Often, I would like to `grep` and do not always want the script to terminate execution if `grep` has an exit status of `1` indicating pattern not found.

Somethings I have tried to solve this problem are as follows:

(Try I)
If `set +o pipefail` and invoke grep with something like `grep 'p' | wc -l` then I get the desired behaviour until a future maintainer enables `pipefail`. Also, I like enabling `pipefail` so this does not work for me.

(Try II)
Use a `sed` or `awk` and only print lines matching pattern, then `wc` matched lines to test for matched pattern. I don't like this option because using `sed` to `grep` seems like a workaround for my true problem.

(Try III)
This one is my least favorite - something like: `set +e; grep 'p'; set-e`

Any insight/idioms would be most appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put the grep in an `if` condition, or if you don't care about the exit status, add `|| true`.

Example: `grep` kills the shell

```
$ bash
$ set -e
$ echo $$
33913
$ grep foo /etc/motd
$ echo $$
9233
```

solution 1: throw away the non-zero exit status

```
$ bash
$ set -e
$ echo $$
34074
$ grep foo /etc/motd || true
$ echo $$
34074
```

solution 2: explicitly test the exit status

```
$ if ! grep foo /etc/motd; then echo not found; fi
not found
$ echo $$
34074
```

From the bash man page discussing `set -e`:

> The shell does not exit if the  command
>                         that fails is part of the command list immediately following a **while** or **until**
>                         keyword, part of the test following the **if** or **elif** reserved  words,  part  of
>                         any  command  executed  in  a  **&&** or **││** list except the command following the
>                         final **&&** or **││**, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if  the  command’s
>                         return  value  is  being inverted with **!**.

Comment: Given that bash for a long time did not implement -e correctly, it may be that the documentation is not yet correct. As the text seems to be identical with the bash-3.x man page, please note: all bash versions before bash4.0 did implement -e incorrectly.

Comment: Also note that as the POSIX standard was wrong as well, we changed the POSIX text for error handling with -e in 2009

Comment: @schily Please give pointers to where one may find out what the 'correct' behavior of -e is, what bash < 4 did differently, and what was changed in POSIX.

Comment: The bugs in bash-3 basically make it unusable for `make` as it did not always exit on errors. For the related POSIX discussions, you may like to check http://austingroupbugs.net/

Comment: @schily Could you please be more specific?

Comment: A Lesson learned: I had a professor who taught `sh`. He said your scripts will be portable and your understanding of the shell will be pure. A few years later writing `Bash` in sin, I now understand his insights more clearly. `if test -e "$file"; then ...` makes it clear that we are manipulating control flow based on the `Exit Status` of the commands in the `if` guard.

Answer (score 0):

Another option when caring about exit status:

```
    FOUND=$(grep whatever here) || true     
    if [ -z $FOUND ]; then
      echo "not found"
    else
      echo "found"
    fi
```