# Netstat Killing Bash Process

Tags: bash, netstat

I have a bit of bash script like this:

```
echo "Number of Connections: "
Conns=$(netstat -an | grep -c ‘8800.*OK’)
echo "Done"
```

It appears to stop processing after netstat.  The output I get is:

```
Number of Connections:
```

When I try it this way:

```
echo "Number of Connections: "
netstat -an | grep -c ‘8800.*OK’
echo "Done"
```

It proves the netstat is working but stopping the process, the output looks like this:

```
Number of Connections:
0
```

Is there a way to stop netstat from stopping the script from continuing?

Thanks

Comment: Does `netstat -an` actually finish, or is it hanging for some reason? Try running `netstat -an | grep -c '8800.*OK'` at the command line, and see if it finishes or hangs. Also, do you really have curly quotes around the `grep` pattern? They need to be plain quotes to work right.

Comment: It does work OK at the command line, inside the script it terminates

Comment: Do you use `set -e` (or something similar) in the script? If so, it'll exit if `grep` doesn't find any matches (and hence exits with a failure status).

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes!  That was the problem, thanks!

Comment: Glad that solved it! This question should probably be marked as a duplicate, then (this and similar problems happen a lot; see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for an extended allegory about why this is).

Comment: Yep, the issue was completely unrelated to the question, happy to close. Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicates: ["Understand why a bash script is not executing main?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322152/understand-why-a-bash-script-is-not-executing-main) and ["`set -e` and `grep` idiom for preventing premature exit from shell script when pattern not found"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235017/set-e-and-grep-idiom-for-preventing-premature-exit-from-shell-script-when-p).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to echo Conns to get it printed

```
echo $Conns
```

Comment: It doesnt get to that line, it runs the line with netstat and terminates